# How memset() works in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memset

I created a boolean 2D array and used `memset` like this :

```
bool chk[3][3];

memset(chk, 1, 9*sizeof(chk[0]));
```

I got output as expected using the following blocks of code (got 1 in every row )

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        cout<<chk[i][j] <<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

but when I tried to manipulate the array I got unexpected result

and then I tried with

```
memset(chk, 1, 9*sizeof(chk[0][0]));
```

and this time everything was fine and got my expected result(after manipulation)

Can you please help me pointing out what exactly happened in memset() ?

Comment: `sizeof(chk[0]) == sizeof(bool[3]) == 3*sizeof(bool)`. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of buffer overrun.

Comment: How big is a `bool` on your system?

Comment: if you are sure that you'll always have a true array (and not, by any chance, a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory) the safest bet is to simply use `sizeof(chk)`. Obviously, using a literal `9` is error prone to changes in the array's dimensions (an issue which is independent of the type and hence size mismatch in `sizeof(chk[0])`).

Comment: `memset`'s not the best tool for this because each byte of each `bool` is going to be set to one. Fix the sizing issue and try this with an `int` and you'll see you get output something like 16843009 rather than 1. You get away with it with bool because everything that isn't 0 is true, but you did many times the work

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie why divide?

Comment: @Swordfish Because he shouldn't use memset, unless setting it to 0, and in that case he should use value initialization instead. So he needs size of array, not the size of storage used by array.And hardcoding array sizes is inviting a bad day to happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memset` call in  your first code snippet has three problems:

1. The size calculation is incorrect. Instead of `9*sizeof(chk[0])` you could use `3*sizeof(chk[0])`. But really you should just use `sizeof(chk)`, because you have a local variable, not a pointer, as you would have with a formal argument.
2. The assumption that memory representation of `true` is bitpattern 1, is not guaranteed by the standard. In practice it will hold, but it would be far better to use the value `true` directly instead of a needless assumption.
3. In C++ simply zero-initialize the variable to make it all zeroes, e.g. `bool chk[3][3] = {};`, or use `std::fill` to fill an array with a given value, e.g. `fill( &chk[0][0], &chk[0][0] + 9, true );`.

---

Addendum: to be pedantic, in point 1 there is an assumption that a `bool` is 1 byte. That's also an assumption that holds in practice but is not guaranteed by the standard. Happily it's not an issue for use of `std::fill`.

Comment: Zero initialization  won't set the values to true either.

Comment: @user2079303: You can use `std::fill` for that. For increasing values in an array of integers you can use `std::iota`. These are more type safe functions.

Comment: +2 for fill, if I could. There is no guarantee that a `bool` is 1 byte, so a memset may write funny patterns, as @user4581301 already observed.

Comment: Is iterating the first sub-array allowed beyond its bounds, such that you iterate the sibling arrays? I've seen answers on SO, that claim this is UB.

Comment: @user2079303: The standard guarantees, via the requirements on `sizeof`, that the array is contiguous with no padding. So yes it's OK.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf regardless of that guarantee, the standard also says that  `When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer ... If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, ... otherwise, the behavior is undefined`. `&chk[0][0] + 9` is outside the bounds of `chk[0]`.

Comment: Consider `auto p = &chk[0][2]`. Now we do `p += 1`. That's OK. We have `p == &chk[1][0]`, at the start of a new sub-array. So we can again do `p += 1`. And so on. After some more such operations, if we started with `p = &chk[0][0]`, and did this 9 times, we have effectively computed `&chk[0][0] + 9` without any formal UB involved. Then there is someone's *interpretation* of the standard that if do this directly, with +9, instead of nine times +1, there's UB. That's nonsense. It might be a defect in the standard but that, I think, is not relevant to this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(chk[0])` is `sizeof(bool[3])` which is obviously different from `sizeof(chk[0][0])` which is `sizeof(bool)`.

With `memset(chk, 1, 9*sizeof(chk[0]));` you write beyond the bounds of the array `chk` and get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what the documentation of `std::memset` says:

> If count is greater than the size of the object pointed to by dest, the behavior is undefined.

In the first code, `9*sizeof(chk[0])` is greater than the size of `chk`, and therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

`memset(chk, 1, sizeof chk)` would be simpler, and obviously correct as far as the size is concerned.

Comment: Considering the "New User" hand you might elaborate what type and likely size `chk[0]` has... it's not entirely obvious given C's and C++'s funny array semantics.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(array)` obviously would return size of array in bytes. In first case the array you submitted to the operator is one of sub-arrays. Multidimensional arrays in C++ aren't. They are single-dimensional arrays of arrays. Do `sizeof(chk)` to evaluate size of full array and divide it by `sizeof(chk[0][0])` to get amount of elements. Don't use `memset` because if would do some strange thing to binary representation of bool, use `std::fill`.

Comment: "Do sizeof(chk) to evaluate size of full array and divide it by sizeof(chk[0][0]) to get amount of elements." i find this misleading since the question is about `memset()` which takes the number of bytes and not the number of elements.

Comment: @Swordfish memset is the wrong tool, as Swift pointed out; the number of elements is usable in fill, as in Alf's example.